# Random walk on 2d lattice with obstacles

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walks, recreational-mathematics

Consider a random work on $L=\mathbb Z^2$ endowed with obstacles (i.e each cell $(x,y)$ of $L$ may contain a obstacle, i.e the random walk halts whenever it hits such a cell). Let $P(x,y) = 1$ if cell $(x,y) \in L$ contains an obstacle, and $0$ otherwise. Thus $P$ is a parameter of the problem. Finally, let $\theta(P) \in [0, 1]$ be the probability that the walk started at the origin $(0,0)$ eventually returns there.

> **Question.** Given $\alpha \in [0,1)$, what are general conditions on $P$ which ensure $\theta(P)>\alpha$?

For example, it is known since Polya (see page 9 of [this article](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/%7Ekozdron/Research/Talks/duke_polya.pdf)) that, if $P(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y) \in L$ (i.e there are no obstacles), then $\theta(P) =1$.

Comment: A random *word*, a random *work*, or a random *walk*? :-)

Comment: More to the point: if there is at least one obstacle, there is non-zero probability the random walk will hit it before returning to zero, and so $\theta(P) < 1$ — if I understand correctly the question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I meant to ask $\theta(P) > 0$ (and not $\theta(P)=1$). Fixed.

Comment: I do not think I have anything interesting to say with regard to Q2, which seems to be a very interesting question, but Q1 again seems to be flawed: if there is a positive probability that one of the neighboring states of the origin is not a trap, then clearly $\theta(P) > 0$, and otherwise $\theta(P) = 0$..

Comment: Indeed Q1 was still flawed. Thanks for spotting this. Now removed. Thus my only question is Q2.